# failed to open stream in my php source

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

i get an error in my php source...(im not master of php)

```
    $API_KEY = '246010911:AAFVhj7jc4kXUPfBH1**************';
$chatid = $update->callback_query->message->chat->id;
$from_id2 = $update->callback_query->from->id;
$get1 = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$API_KEY/getChatMember?chat_id=$chatid&user_id=".$from_id2);
```

and My Error :

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot****/getChatMember?chat_id=&amp;user_id=): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

how can i fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `$API_KEY`, `$chatid`, `$from_id2` after using it.

Try this with the correct API_KEY.

```
$API_KEY = '246010911:AAFVhj7jc4kXUPfBH1**************';
$chatid = $update->callback_query->message->chat->id;
$from_id2 = $update->callback_query->from->id;

$get1 = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$API_KEY/getChatMember?chat_id=$chatid&user_id=".$from_id2);
```

Comment: same warning? possible to share a screenshot?